# Browsers report no internet while ping works and windows reports connection

Tags: windows-10, internet, internet-connection

On my Windows 10 laptop from the browser (Chrome, Firefox, Waterfox, Edge) trying to access internet sites reports that it can't connect after a while, but ping works. Accessing local servers is fine. Accessing sites through an explicit local proxy in Waterfox also works.

After a reboot the browsers work for a bit, but then fail.

putty telnet seems to work fine.

I've already tried steps from:

[Ping works fine, but no Internet connection in browser](https://superuser.com/questions/1211083/ping-works-fine-but-no-internet-connection-in-browser)

```
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ip reset reset.log
netsh advfirewall reset
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
route /f
```

I've done a wireshark and it shows that TCP connections are getting reset (RST packets from the machine as far as I can tell).

The machine has Sophos Anti-virus installed. MS Office also, but not much else.

EDIT:
I have now tried:

- Disabled the firewall - the problem still occurs.
- Tried Opera browser as well
- Tried wget from powershell - also reports the connection being reset, at the same time that the browsers are not working
- Tried Privoxy - also not working when browsers direct aren't working.
- Removed Sophos entirely in case that was causing the problem.
- Done a malware scan with Sophos Virus Removal Tool, which found nothing.
- Updated the wireless driver for the built-in wireless adapter.
- Tried a USB wireless driver.
- Tried a wired connection, which seemed to work, but maybe we didn't leave it long enough.
- Flushing the caches of Chrome, which appeared to work for a while.

Any ideas for how to get browsing working reliably?

Comment: Have you tried updating your Sophos and running it?  The only time I've had browsers not work when the internet was working for other apps was when there was a virus/malware that wanted to prevent the user from downloading a tool to remove it.  That used to be a fairly common "virus removal tool prevention" technique a few years back.  You might also want to check your Internet Options and check the proxy settings.

Comment: I would try disabling your firewall temporarily and flushing or bypassing your browsers' caches when the problem occurs, to see if this allows connections. if it does, you will have a better idea of where to look for a cause.

Comment: We have now resolved the problem with a windows reset (keeping user data)

Comment: Looking back - the issue happened again, and was again fixed with a Windows Reset. We think the most likely candidate was connecting her phone via USB to the computer. Maybe setting some kind of alternative network route?