# Odd Ethernet issue

Tags: internet, ethernet

I'm having a very strange issue and can't find any way around it.

When I try to browse Internet on any kind of browser, from my Ethernet connection, it does not work. Some other applications do not work too (i.e.: Steam). However when I ping either my router or an external host, it works.

Everything works fine, on the same computer, with the WiFi connection.
Everything works fine, on another computer, when I put the exact same Ethernet cable.

I tried various things such as changing the MAC address of my Ethernet card in case it was blocked somewhere but with no success.

I also tried to apply the commands suggested in this post but without success. [Ping works fine, but no Internet connection in browser](https://superuser.com/questions/1211083/ping-works-fine-but-no-internet-connection-in-browser/1211136)

Does anyone have any idea on how I could fix it?

Comment: What exactly is not working in your Web-Browser? Is it working when you disable the WiFi-Interface? Any static DNS configurations?

Comment: The behaviour is the following:
1) Try to browse webpage
2) Establishing secure connection message on bottom left of the browser for few second
3) On Chrome, get the errors: ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED or ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

It is still not working with the WiFi interface disabled.

Yes I have a static DNS configuration, but I tried without and it is not working either.

Comment: I Don't think this is a DNS problem anymore with those errors in Chrome. Are other Web-Browsers working? Can you access HTTP/HTTPS via a command line tool (e.g. curl)?

Comment: Yes all browsers do not work, I tried curl but it does not work either. I also just tried to SSH to my server but it didn't work either (wanted to make sure it's not something on port 80 on only). Thanks!

Comment: This could be IPv4/v6 related... Try checking the routing tables and compare them in both cases (wifi/ethernet).