# WSL binds all ports, lose network access: Unable to connect

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL for some node development on a Windows 10 machine (build 1803). Inevitably, within a few hours of starting WSL, all ports on the system become bound. At this point, no new network connections open, and I effectively lose network access until I restart.

```
netstat -qn |findstr BOUND
```

This shows all TCP ports bound up to the max, such as:

```
 TCP    0.0.0.0:60755          0.0.0.0:0              BOUND
```

I've tried using ipconfig to reset the windows side adapter, killing all WSL processes, and a bunch of other things, but nothing unbinds the ports. I'd like to be able to use my computer without having to restart every few hours.

I was able to find an open issue with limited info: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2523
but no solutions or workarounds.

Any way to reset WSL or open the ports would be much appreciated!

Comment: What process/processes is/are responsible? if you run: `netstat -qno | find "BOUND"`, what is the PID (last column) and what does this map to in TaskManager/Tasklist.exe?

Comment: It seems to be adb, part of a cli for the Expo project I have. I expect it to open connections, as it's for remote debugging. But killing it or even WSL as a whole doesn't release the ports.

Comment: It is surprising that killing the process doesn't clean up.  Can you run the following PowerShell command and link the results:
`get-nettcpconnection -state BOUND -OwningProcess ((Get-Process adb).ID)[0] | select LocalAddress, LocalPort, state`  Note: I've put the process in as `adb` is that correct?

Comment: By randomly killing processes, I found that 'init' in 'Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs' seems to actually terminate WSL and release the ports. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Temporary fix:** use the Task Manager to "End process tree" for `adb`, `wslhost.exe`, and `wslbridge.exe`.  However, this kills WSL and anything running on WSL.

**Permanent fix:** it looks like this is a known WSL bug described on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2913) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3951), and [Microsoft fixed it in Build 18890](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/blob/live/WSL/release-notes.md#build-18890).  However, as of May 2019, Build 18890 is well ahead of the stable builds of Windows, so you need to enroll in the Windows Insider Program to get it.