# Ping working but fine but the computer does not browse to any website using any browser

Tags: networking, dns, browser, ping, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My cmd pings fine to 8.8.8.8 as well as other common adresses but when i try to browse to a website, connection times out. I tried the solution as mentioned here and turns out using the combination of commands (coupled with a restart) -

```
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ip reset reset.log
```

did the trick, but when i leave the laptop alone for a while, the same issue re-occours, and i have to run the 2 commands and restart again. This happened spontaneously.

The above commands i have taken from the solution posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1211083/ping-works-fine-but-no-internet-connection-in-browser/1211136#1211136?newreg=b6d5635855334aaf95c85534f75baf39)
I had installed WSL2 with Ubuntu and docker about 10-15 days ago, i have read through [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1399063/wsl-binds-all-ports-lose-network-access-unable-to-connect) solution but my windows build is 19043, well above the mentioned build.
I've been using a hotspot all this while in a new city, but the internet works pretty fine on my phone.
[My system description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FO1Fj.png)
A few screen shots of `Get-NetTCPConnection`command run -
[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuYO4.png)
[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAhN8.png)
[third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHiKF.png)

PLease inform me if any other details are required.

EDIT - a new command is also sometimes now required along with the previously mentioned commands - `netsh advfirewall reset`

Comment: (1) Is there any chance that your laptop is hibernating at any point before it stops working?  (2) Is there anything going on in the background that could be removing, compressing, or encrypting temp files?

Comment: Not really, no. I don't use the hibernate feature really. The funny thing is, i came back home yesterday and the laptop works fine with the wifi, but still no luck with the hotspot. 
So now the complete story is Hotspot and wifi works fine of Friday, i go to a new city and hotspot broke, couldn't test wifi, come back to home on monday, wifi still works but hotspot still gives the same problem.