# TCP Ports not being released on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, browser, port

For a couple of months my PC's internet has 'stopped working' after a few hours of operation, very similar to what is described on [this super user post](https://superuser.com/questions/1211083/ping-works-fine-but-no-internet-connection-in-browser). It looks to be due to TCP Port exhaustion. Running [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/troubleshoot-tcpip-port-exhaust#method-1) Powershell command results in firefox or chrome (depending on which browser I am using) appearing at the top of the list with hundreds and eventually thousands of ports. Example:

```
951 Bound, 21280       firefox                  {MSFT_NetTCPConnection (InstanceID = "0.0.0.0??51531??0.0.0.0??0"), MSFT_NetTCPConnection (InstanceID = "0.0.0.0??51530??0.0.0.0??0"), MSFT_NetTCPConnection (InstanceID = "0.0.0.0??51529??0.0.0.0??0"), MSFT_Ne...
```

Note that the state of the port is BOUND - so there are no corresponding entries in tools like TCPView and CPort. Empirically it appears that opening new websites causes this number to shoot up; it appears relatively stable if no new windows are being opened. Killing chrome/firefox does not free up the ports.

I'm running Windows 10 Version 1803 (Build 17134.950).

What could be happening?

Comment: I'm not getting this behavior. Bound port means that it is opened but nobody is listening. This is perhaps some runaway extension(s) you have installed? Try to launch the browsers in Safe/Incognito mode without extensions to verify. If it still happens, try to boot in Safe Mode With Network to see if this is some installed third-party app.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc. I don't think it's an extension since chrome and firefox exhibit the same behaviour. Booting firefox into safe mode did nothing.  I've also noticed some other programs having a large number of bound ports (but less noticeable since they don't open as many ports as browsers). I tried to boot up into windows safe mode with networking but wifi wasn't detected. It's like programs aren't releasing their ports - eg: after killing firefox the ports are still bound but against a blank process name. Could it potentially be my Bitdefender antivirus?

Comment: It's possible it's Bitdefender, and that's easy to verify. Ports not closed by the application may take minutes to disappear, so you should wait after killing firefox.

Comment: It sounds very similar to what is described in https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2913.

Comment: I'm going to try to figure out how to disable Bitdefender - this has proven more difficult than it should be in the past!

Comment: Try also to reduce [TcpTimedWaitDelay](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc938217%28v=technet.10%29) to 30 seconds or less. This is a mitigating measure for misbehaving software, and not a solution.

Comment: RE: waiting after killing firefox, I've waited about 30 minutes and the ports are still bound.  883 Bound, 23444                                {MSFT_NetTCPConnection (InstanceID = "0.0.0.0??52119??0.0.0.0??0")... Note there is no process name since firefox has been killed.

Comment: Try to reduce TcpTimedWaitDelay to see if that affects the time waited.

Comment: I uninstalled BitDefender and noticed an immediate improvement (opening 20 tabs resulted in the usual increase in # of Bound ports, but then closing them released the ports). I've reinstalled Bitdefender seems like ports are being released still, so maybe an errant installation of Bitdefender. I'm going to keep an eye on it and report back if the problem reappears (with Bitdefender still installed), but looks like the issue was/is a Bitdefender install.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was an installation of Bitdefender.
- With Bitdefender uninstalled, the issue appeared fixed: bound ports were being released when tabs were closed
- With Bitdefender reinstalled, it appears that the issue *continues* to be resolved.