# Ping works, but browser/telnet does not

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, dns, ping

I am on Windows 10. I am connected to the internet via Wireless. As soon as I boot, the internet connection works fine for a few minutes, but stops working after that

After it stops working, ping still works. So does nslookup

```
nslookup www.google.com
Server:  dsldevice.lan
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.google.com
Addresses:  2404:6800:4002:814::2004
          142.250.194.228
```

Tracert works too

```
tracert www.google.com

Tracing route to www.google.com [142.250.194.196]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  dsldevice.lan [192.168.1.1]
  2     5 ms     4 ms     4 ms  abts-north-dynamic-1.128.97.117.airtelbroadband.in [117.97.128.1]
  3     5 ms     5 ms     5 ms  125.16.34.237
  4     5 ms     7 ms     5 ms  182.79.154.73
  5     8 ms     8 ms     7 ms  142.250.161.56
  6     7 ms     8 ms     9 ms  172.253.69.191
  7     7 ms     8 ms    34 ms  142.251.52.207
  8     8 ms     7 ms     8 ms  del12s07-in-f4.1e100.net [142.250.194.196]
```

Browsing it in *any* browser doesn't work, and neither does telnet

```
telnet www.google.com 80
Connecting To www.google.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connect failed
```

I have tried flushing the dns cache, still doesn't work after that

```
ipconfig /flushdns

Windows IP Configuration

Successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.
```

This is the result of `ipconfig /all`

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DESKTOP-I28LDEV
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek Gaming GbE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C8-D9-D2-83-88-F0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C2-B6-F9-13-DF-3F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 4:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-D3-FA-34-58
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C0-B6-F9-13-DF-3F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.4(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, May 14, 2021 9:56:45 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, May 15, 2021 9:56:45 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C0-B6-F9-13-DF-43
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

I have also tried disabling the firewall, still doesn't work. I have also tried the steps in [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/1211083/ping-works-fine-but-no-internet-connection-in-browser), after rebooting it works for a while, then same issue

I have also tried uninstalling the Wireless adaptor, and rebooting. Again works for a few minutes, then same issue

Comment: any antivirus that might interfere with network connections?

Comment: No antivirus is installed except Windows Defender